# OpenGL does not render objects if I use malloc() instead of stack arrays?

Tags: c++, opengl, malloc, game-engine

In my 2D OpenGL Game Project in C++ I am now trying to read the "quantity of enemies" from a file and then render these enemies. Each enemy consisting of 2 triangles with texture (2D sprite).

I could implement rendering with an array declaration for the struct holding individual "enemy" data (e.g. position of each enemy), but if I try to use malloc to dynamically allocate memory according to the number I am reading from the file, nothing is rendered.

What am I doing wrong? I really would like to use malloc as the number of enemies will vary and I wouldn't like to work with a fixed-size array.

About the code below: basically one class called "gameEnemies" holds a struct called "Enemy"; each time you create an object of class "gameEnemies" the object should allocate enough memory to create as many enemies as per what is defined in the external file.

1. This is the struct with declaration of fixed-size array - this one is working.

   ```
   struct Enemy {


       Point3D center; //object attributes
       Vector3D direction; //gets updated with current direction after rotations to show where object is facing at
       Vector3D collDir; //which direction collided

       float deltaX;
       float deltaY;
       float prevDeltaX;
       float prevDeltaY;
       float deltaA;
       float prevDeltaA;
       float speed;
       bool collided;

       int qtyCollided; //with how many other objects it collided

       bool alive;

       //matrices below passed as uniforms to shader
       //rotation
       Transform4D rotateTransf{ 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };
       //moves to world position after being drawn with center at origin (0,0)
       Transform4D modelTransf{  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };

       //translation of texture (animation), passed as uniform to shader
       Transform4D transformTex{ 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };

   }enemies[MAX_TMX_ENEMIES];
   ```
2. This is the struct which is not working - same as above however declaring the pointer instead.

   ```
   struct Enemy {


       Point3D center; //object attributes
       Vector3D direction; //gets updated with current direction after rotations to show where object is facing at
       Vector3D collDir; //which direction collided

       float deltaX;
       float deltaY;
       float prevDeltaX;
       float prevDeltaY;
       float deltaA;
       float prevDeltaA;
       float speed;
       bool collided;

       int qtyCollided; //with how many other objects it collided

       bool alive;

       //matrices below passed as uniforms to shader
       //rotation
       Transform4D rotateTransf{ 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };
       //moves to world position after being drawn with center at origin (0,0)
       Transform4D modelTransf{  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };

       //translation of texture (animation), passed as uniform to shader
       Transform4D transformTex{ 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };

   }*enemies;
   ```
3. Below is the loop that allocates memory plus initializes value - seems to work as I can access data and I get no errors at compile time nor at running time:

   ```
   enemies = (Enemy*)malloc(sizeof(Enemy) * totalObj);

   for (int j = 0; j < totalObj; j++) //loop objects in the group
   {

       enemies[j].center = mapObj.getObjects(i)[j].center;
       enemies[j].direction = Vector3D{1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
       enemies[j].deltaX = 0.0f;
       enemies[j].deltaY = 0.0f;
       enemies[j].prevDeltaX = 0.0f;
       enemies[j].prevDeltaY = 0.0f;
       enemies[j].deltaA = 0.0f;
       enemies[j].prevDeltaA = 0.0f;
       enemies[j].speed = 6.0f;
       enemies[j].collided = false;
       enemies[j].collDir = Vector3D{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.f };
       enemies[j].qtyCollided = 0;
       enemies[j].alive = true;

       enemies[j].modelTransf.SetTranslation(Point3D{ enemies[j].center.x, enemies[j].center.y, 0.0f }); //initial translation to world position
       enemies[j].rotateTransf.SetRotationZ(enemies[j].deltaA); //initial rotation = 0
       enemies[j].transformTex.SetTranslation(Point3D{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }); //no transform on texture upon object creation

   }
   ```
4. Below is the loop to initialize values when the array declaration is used - only change is that the malloc is not preset:

   ```
   /*EXCLUDED: enemies = (Enemy*)malloc(sizeof(Enemy) * totalObj);*/
   for (int j = 0; j < totalObj; j++) //loop objects in the group
   {

       enemies[j].center = mapObj.getObjects(i)[j].center;
       enemies[j].direction = Vector3D{1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
       enemies[j].deltaX = 0.0f;
       enemies[j].deltaY = 0.0f;
       enemies[j].prevDeltaX = 0.0f;
       enemies[j].prevDeltaY = 0.0f;
       enemies[j].deltaA = 0.0f;
       enemies[j].prevDeltaA = 0.0f;
       enemies[j].speed = 6.0f;
       enemies[j].collided = false;
       enemies[j].collDir = Vector3D{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.f };
       enemies[j].qtyCollided = 0;
       enemies[j].alive = true;

       enemies[j].modelTransf.SetTranslation(Point3D{ enemies[j].center.x, enemies[j].center.y, 0.0f }); //initial translation to world position
       enemies[j].rotateTransf.SetRotationZ(enemies[j].deltaA); //initial rotation = 0
       enemies[j].transformTex.SetTranslation(Point3D{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }); //no transform on texture upon object creation

   }
   ```
5. Below the common render function: works well with array, doesn't render a single object if I use malloc:

   ```
   void render()
   {
       // shader to use
       objShader.use();
       objShader.setVec4("orthoTex", orthoTex); //common to all instances
       //for texture
       glEnable(GL_BLEND);
       glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
       glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

       glBindVertexArray(VAO);
       for(int i = 0; i< totalEnemies; i++)
       {
           //pass relevant uniforms to shader before drawing each instance
           objShader.setVec4("transfTex", enemies[i].transformTex);
           objShader.setVec4("modelTransf", enemies[i].modelTransf);
           objShader.setVec4("rotateTransf", enemies[i].rotateTransf);
           //draw
           glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
       }
       glBindVertexArray(0);
   }
   ```
6. The struct Enemy is inside a struct called "gameEnemies" - not sure if this changes anything but just in case. This is because all the "Enemies" will share common attributes like the OpenGL buffers, vertices, shader, etc.

   ```
   struct gameEnemies {

   protected:

       //arrays with vertex data and indices
       float vertices[16]; //holds vertex + texture coordinates for VBO (order: obj.x, obj.y, tex.x, tex.y, obj.x...)
       unsigned int indices[6]; //holds triangle indices for the EBO

       //the OpenGL buffers
       unsigned int VBO, VAO, EBO;

       //object shader
       Shader objShader;

       //texture ID
       unsigned int texture;

       float width;
       float height;

       int totalEnemies;
       int enemyMapPos; //position in the MAP OBJECT (which group) where enemies of specicif "label" for this handler are

       //transform texture coordinates to world (png file) coordinates (0,0 //bottom left to 1,1//top right)
       Transform4D orthoTex;

       struct Enemy {


           Point3D center; //object attributes
           Vector3D direction; //gets updated with current direction after rotations to show where object is facing at
           Vector3D collDir; //which direction collided

           float deltaX;
           float deltaY;
           float prevDeltaX;
   ```

   etc...

Comment: Why do you use `malloc` in C++!?

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].  Feel free to use [this](https://github.com/genpfault/glfw-mcve-base/blob/master/src/main.cpp) as a base.

Comment: I am new to C++; the only thing I could think of was malloc. Now I am clear it shouldn't be used. Thanks!

Comment: @JBN -- `#include <type_traits> … std::cout << std::is_pod<Enemy>()` -- if that prints out `0`, then your type cannot be "malloc"-ed".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie But even then, there is no reason to prefer `malloc` over `new`.

Comment: Yes, I know.  Just letting @JBN know there are techniques that you can use at compile-time to test for these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `malloc` in C++ is, except in very special cases, wrong.

`malloc` allocates memory, but does not construct any object in it. Trying to use the memory as if you had created instances of `Enemy` in them causes undefined behavior.

You need to use `new[]`. It allocates memory and constructs the objects:

```
enemies = new Enemy[totalObj];
```

You destruct these objects and free the memory later with `delete[] enemies`.

---

However, you should not use manual dynamic memory management. Use `std::vector` instead:

```
std::vector<Enemy> enemies;

enemies.resize(totalObj);
```

---

It is also very unclear why you initialize some of the members in the class definition with default member initializers, but others in an external loop.

Either use default member initializers for all members or write a proper constructor for your `struct` doing all the initialization.

Your current approach is confusing and less efficient because the memory must be iterated twice.

It is also dangerous, because if you forget to set one of the uninitialized members when after constructing the `Enemy`s, then you will have undefined behavior when using it.

Comment: Thank you. It seems I definitely shouldn't be using malloc. Your solution works perfectly. I will work on a constructor now, I know it is a bit messy currently. I am just a hobbyist programmer - C++ is new to me and it's been years since I wrote some code in C.

Comment: @JBN C and C++ use very different programming styles. I'd suggest investing in a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). There are also books for programmers with prior programming experience in other languages in that list.

Comment: Thanks for the list. I have just bought C++ Primer 5th Edition actually and was happy to see it is recommended. I've now replaced all the other calls to malloc in my code with the std::vector and it is all working good! Actually made my life a lot easier. Really appreciated it!

Comment: I went through the "containers" chapter on C++ Primer 5th Edition and it covers all I needed. Thanks once more for the advice.